# Sequence contains no elements error but I want to check for null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have the following problem:

```
public Boolean Exists(String userName)
{
    IRepository<User> = new UserRepository();
    User user = userRepository.First(u => u.Name == userName);

    if (user == null) return false;

    // Exists!
    return true;
}
```

The problem is now, that I can't check the User object for null. Before I get there, I get an `InvalidOperationException` saying "**The sequence contains no elements**".

This seems really weird to me, especially as I don't want to establish control flow with exceptions (e.g. encapsulate in try..catch and return true/false in the respective parts).

What's going on here? Is this normal or is there something wrong with my respository (hint?!)

**By the way, this code works *perfectly* when the element that I'm looking for exists (the User is retrieved etc.). It only doesn't work when there is no match.**

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Use FirstOrDefault instead of First.  This will return null in the face of an empty collection.

```
IRepository<User> = new UserRepository();
User user = userRepository.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Name == userName);
```

Comment: @Tomas, I actually got in ahead of you but I made a post answer edit to actually include a code sample.  The second edit was 2 seconds behind :)

Comment: Thats true Jared got in first :D (by 2 seconds.. it was showing Jared 48 secs ago and Tomas 46 secs ago).

Thank you Gentlemen!!!!

Answer (score 23):

Try changing `.First()` to `.FirstOrDefault()`.

Answer (score 12):

Use `.FirstOrDefault()` to prevent that error

Answer (score 0):

`FirstOrDefault` is very important. But for your exact use, you can also say `Any`:

```
public bool Exists(string userName)
{
    IRepository<User> userRepository = new UserRepository();
    return userRepository.Any(u => u.Name == userName);
}
```