# LINQ : exception as " Sequence contains no elements"

Tags: c#, .net, linq

While execution of following linq, I get this exception:

> " Sequence contains no elements"

Linq code:

```
   newGradeRow[rowCnt + 1 + "Grade " + ExamName] = 
      objDataSet.Tables[1].Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
      .Where(p => Convert.ToDecimal(p["EMG_MARKS_ABOVE"]) <= extSubMarks  
         && extSubMarks <= Convert.ToDecimal(p["EMG_MARKS_BELOW"]))
      .Select(p => Convert.ToString(p["EMG_GRADE_NAME"]))
      .First();
```

Can any one help me on this?

Comment: The exception is clear - one of the lists you are working with is empty and is not returning any results.

Comment: as i mentioned in the question while execution i get an exception as "Sequence contains no elements". can you please tell me why i am getting that exception or what is wrong in the code. i am new to .net.

Comment: I think your collection has no items.  What do *you* think you should do?  This question is an exercise in basic thought.

Comment: Not sure why this was closed, it's a pretty basic question but would serve as a good way to answer this simple question for future linq newbies

Comment: This shouldn't have been closed. I'm faced with this same exception, and I can't find any answers anywhere else. Oh well. I'll just ask again. :-)

Comment: This question was closed for wrong reason. It's straightforward, known what's being asked e has an correct answer with some upvotes (that shows that other people had same doubt and found answer helpful). Perhaps, it should be closed by duplicate.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324199, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/942545,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18115926...

Answer (score 51):

The exception is thrown in the `First` method call if the sequence is empty as it is stated in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976.aspx). In this case it is better to use the [FirstOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx) method - it will return the default value (in specific case `null`) and no exception will be thrown.

Answer (score 7):

Start by breaking it up. Your current code offers no grip for a debugger.

```
var r1 = objDataSet.Tables[1].Rows;
var r2 = r1.Cast<DataRow>();
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("r2: {0}", r2.Count());
var r3 = r2.Where(p => Convert.ToDecimal(p["EMG_MARKS_ABOVE"]) <= extSubMarks  
            && extSubMarks <= Convert.ToDecimal(p["EMG_MARKS_BELOW"]));
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("r3: {0}", r3.Count());
var r4 = r3.Select(p => Convert.ToString(p["EMG_GRADE_NAME"]));
var r5 = r4.First();

newGradeRow[rowCnt + 1 + "Grade " + ExamName] = r5;
```

Comment: Whilst the code is a bit fiddly, it is pretty clear that the ONLY thing there that would throw that exception is the call to First() which requires 1 or more elements.

Comment: @BenRobinson, Agreed, but is it empty before or after the `Where()` ? I would want to know.

Comment: Fair enough, but I would suggest you mention that it is the call to `First()` that throws and explain the difference between `First()` and `FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: I think Henk's point is to break up the code for debugging purposes.  Lines 1 and 2 could also throw exceptions.

Answer (score 3):

It's difficult to say WHICH sequence has no elements when you have so many strung together in the same line of code.  Try breaking your code down to multiple lines and then debug it.  This will make it more readable as well.

```
var myVariable = objDataSet.Tables[1]; 
var myEntity = myVariable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Where(
  p => Convert.ToDecimal(p["EMG_MARKS_ABOVE"]) <= extSubMarks
  && extSubMarks <= Convert.ToDecimal(p["EMG_MARKS_BELOW"]))
  .Select(p => Convert.ToString(p["EMG_GRADE_NAME"])).FirstOrDefault();
```

If the problem is somewhere in your Lambda expression, you may want to break it out into a foreach loop (just for the sake of debugging & having access to the data within the immediate window of VS).

Comment: ThYou have changed the last call to `FirstOrDefault()` which will get rid of the exception but you haven't mentioned that which is a bit odd.

Comment: My mistake.  I prefer using the FirstOrDefault() extension method over First() for better exception handling.  You can then check for nulls afterward before proceeding.

Answer (score 1):

You should take care about this that:
What Linq Expression/ query does not contain any record then you can not use `Single()` and `First()`.

On the place `Single()` in your Lambda expression use `FirstOrDefault()`

Answer (score 0):

`objDataSet.Tables[1]` is empty?

Perhaps the data is in `objDataSet.Tables[0]` ?

Either way, you can test with `objDataSet.Tables.Count() > 0`

You can do the same for Rows: `objDataSet.Tables[1].Rows.Count() > 0`

Comment: Or no elements pass the `Where` filter. The exception is raised by `First` when it is given an empty list.