# LINQ: Sequence contains no elements error

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am trying to solve an error with using LINQ.
I am pulling an XML node value using LINQ. The problem I am facing is when the node is not present in the XML I'm getting `Sequence contains no elements` error.
I tried using DefaultIfEmpty, Singleordefault, and Firstordefault. 
But then it throws a nullpointer exception. I guess I'm not above methods correctly.
How can use one of these to solve the poblem?

Here's the LINQ code that I'm using.

```
var costnode6 = doc.Root.Descendants(ns + "SERVICEUPGRADES").Single(c => (string)c.Element(ns + "DELIVERYTIME") == "before 3:30 PM").Element(ns + "TOTAL_COST");
        var cost6 = (decimal)costnode6;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `OrDefault` methods return the default value for the type if there is no result, which in your case would be `null`. That means when you do a `.Element(ns + "TOTAL_COST")` after that call, you'll get the `Sequence contains no elements` error if using `Single` or a `Null Reference Exception` if using `SingleOrDefault`.

What you should do is pull the call out and check the result against null:

```
var deliveryTime = doc.Root.Descendants(ns + "SERVICEUPGRADES")
    .SingleOrDefault(c => (string)c.Element(ns + "DELIVERYTIME") == "before 3:30 PM");
if(deliveryTime != null)
{     
    var costnode6 = deliveryTime.Element(ns + "TOTAL_COST");
    var cost6 = (decimal)costnode6;   
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `SingleOrDefault`, but then have a guard clause before trying to use `costnode6`, like this:

```
var costnode6 = doc.Root.Descendants(ns + "SERVICEUPGRADES").SingleOrDefault(c => (string)c.Element(ns + "DELIVERYTIME") == "before 3:30 PM").Element(ns + "TOTAL_COST");

if(costnode6 != null)
{
    var cost6 = (decimal)costnode6;
}
```

This will protect your LINQ query from blowing up, because the `OrDefault` will make the query result `null` if exactly one result is not found; and the `if` condition will protect you from trying to use a `null` object.